# How to take every 3rd element of vector x and save them to a new vector called y? (In R)

Tags: r, vector, indexing

Problem: You are given a vector called x. Write a Code that takes every 3rd element of x and saves them to a new vector called y. Then raise the value of every element in y by 3.

Attempted solution:

```
x[seq(from=3,to=length(x),by=3)]-> y
y<-y+3
```

Am I even close with this?

Comment: That seems correct to me. Were you expecting something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your goal is a bit unprecise, however it seems that you would like to start with the first element of x, and your solution is starting with the 3rd.

Therefore, you should go with something like :

```
y <- x[seq(1, length(x), 3)]
```

in addition, you may encounter issue if the length of x <3 in your example (seq would then expect a negative value for the "by" argument).

in my example, you still would have an issue if x is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is completely write and will work just fine assuming you will take every third element of x for example `x <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15)` and insert that to y and add 3 to that will give an output of `7, 11, 18`, here is the complete code that you can match with yours:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15)

x[seq(from = 3, to = length(x), by = 3)] -> y

y + 3 -> y

print(y)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try `c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)` to index `x`, which takes every 3rd entries of `x`

```
y <- 3 + x[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]
```

or we can use modulo `%%`

```
y <- 3 + x[!seq_along(x) %% 3]
```